# how to solve a run time error in case shift of string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, runtime-error, case-sensitive

```
def swap_case(s):
    for x in s:
        if (x.isupper())==True:
            x=(x.lower())
        else:
            x=(x.upper())
    return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    result = swap_case(s)
    print(result)
```

The above is my code to change the case of an input string. For example, if I input "Python" then my output should be "pYTHON"

Comment: Why not use `str.swapcase` function?

Comment: So what is your error?

Answer (score 1):

First thing **strings are immutable** in python

So you can not change letters within the `string` like elements in `list`

Create an empty `str` and add new elements in it like below (using increment and assign operation`+=`)

```
def swap_case(s):
    new_s = ""
    for i in s:
         if i.isupper():
             new_s += i.lower()
         else:
             new_s += i.upper()
    return new_s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    result = swap_case(s)
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions),

```
def swap_case(s):
    return ''.join([x.lower() if x.isupper() else x.upper() for x in s])
```

OR you can either use the in-built function [swapcase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.swapcase)

`s.swpacase()`

Output

`pYTHON`

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
def swap_case(s):
s_new=''
for x in s:
    if x.isupper():
        x = x.lower()
    else:
        x = x.upper()
    s_new = s_new + x
return s_new
```

s = input('Enter the word : ')
result = swap_case(s)
print(result)